# How do I recover the APFS partition of a Macbook using Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, uefi, data-recovery, macbook, gpt

## Background

I use a Macbook Pro that has High Sierra and Fedora in dual-boot. I wasn't using Fedora so I wanted to try Ubuntu 17.10 and I ran a live USB (booting in EFI mode).

Given that all my work-related files, projects, and other "important stuff" (on the Mac side) are already backed up via either Dropbox or remote Git repositories, I decided to delete Fedora and install Ubuntu without doing a full bitstream image of the drive.

At first I deleted the Fedora related partitions using Gnome Disks (this is OK). I started the Ubuntu installer and I did these steps:

- Selected a language > Continue
- Checked "Download updates while installing Ubuntu" > Continue
- Chose "Something else" for the partitions > Continue
- Mistakenly set the type of `/dev/sda2` as "Physical volume for encryption" and added my password

Please note that I **did not** chose to "Overwrite empty disk space". I also **did not** continue with the installation (I didn't reach the point when it asks you to confirm the new partition table). Rather, I clicked "Back" and then closed the installer immediately.

This should not have written anything to disk. However, the Ubuntu installer decided to write something anyway, it seems.

## Problem

After rebooting quickly, it was clear that something wrong has been written on disk despite never reaching the confirmation step. The type of the partition has been changed and neither rEFInd (which loads correctly) nor the Apple boot screen can find macOS.

This is the output of `lsblk`:

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL              UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squash                                                         /rofs
sda                                                                   
├─sda1 vfat   EFI                67E3-17ED                            
├─sda2 crypto                    9b2ca99d-cf43-4d35-936d-be37db7b950d 
└─sda3
```

Originally, `sda2` was APFS. In macOS Filevault was enabled, however I can't tell if it was using CoreStorage or native APFS encryption (I suspect the latter as it was migrated from an older version with HFS+).

Running `diskutil list` from the Apple Internet recovery yields this:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2: 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC               349.7 GB   disk0s2
   3: 5361644D-6163-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC               1.3 GB     disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *1.3 GB     disk1
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         30.7 KB    disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        1.3 GB     disk1s2
```

The second device is the Internet recovery.

Strangely, also `/dev/sda3` aka `disk0s3` is not recognized, despite never being touched in any way. So the Mac now doesn't even boot the local recovery but it relies on the Internet based one.

Back on Ubuntu, `parted` complains about a corrupted GPT, but `gdisk` thinks it is fine. Here's the output of `parted -l`:

```
Model: ATA APPLE SSD SM0512 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      20.5kB  210MB  210MB   fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      210MB   350GB  350GB
 3      350GB   351GB  1306MB


Error: Both the primary and backup GPT tables are corrupt.  Try making a fresh
table, and using Parted's rescue feature to recover partitions.
```

## Questions

Most importantly, how can I use Ubuntu to fix the GPT table and set the correct file system type for `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda3`?

Secondly, does the Ubuntu installer write stuff on the partition table even before confirming the changes? Is this intended behavior?

Are there chances to recover the system without reinstalling? As I said, I have backups of the valuable data. What worries me is that I will lose a lot of time for reinstalling applications and things like that.

Comment: I wanted to install 17.04 on my MacBook Pro with 10.13 on it. However, I have stopped dreaming because APFS is active on the SSD. 
APFS is not just a file system but, also replaces core storage as a volume manager via 'containers'. Changes to the way GPT works are included in the update. In my mind, this means that none of our current partition managers are APFS-aware, as the filesystem is no longer a free entity within a partition but, is bound to a filesystem and 'container'. Neither Parted nor rEFInd are aware of this new scheme. explained at: https://twocanoes.com/boot-camp-high-sierra/

Comment: @Orian, I see but rEFInd worked fine to dual boot macOS and Fedora for me. Thank you for the link, I will check it out carefully.

Comment: I may be mistaken. But, I think it worked because Fedora was already there before APFS was updated. Mac OS would not have broken it.  I think it would have continued to work until a nonAPFS-aware utility touched the partition map. At any rate, best of luck with it. I would love to know if you come up with any workable solution.

Comment: @Orian, it turns out I was using the old Internet Recovery. The latest one sees the partition table correctly. The problem is not the partition table, it is that Ubuntu **overwrote a whopping 2MB of the APFS container** without confirmations or warnings. Basically I lost some videogame save files and all the installed apps and now I have to reinstall everything again. This is a horrible behavior for a partition manager.

Comment: I'll cut the Ubuntu devs some slack on it. APFS is a totally new animal in the zoo. But, totally agree that it would have been nice  for the partition manager to NOT WRITE anything until user commit though. Good luck with the reload.

Comment: @Orian thank you. I used to tell people "always backup important files" (and this is what I did too). Now I will start telling them "always backup whatever file you have, even if you think it's useless"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> - Mistakenly set the type of `/dev/sda2` as "Physical volume for encryption" and added my password
>
> Please note that I **did not** chose to "Overwrite empty disk space". I also **did not** continue with the installation (I didn't reach the point when it asks you to confirm the new partition table). Rather, I clicked "Back" and then closed the installer immediately.

Given your subsequent problems, I'd say that either the Ubuntu installer wrote to the disk immediately or something else damaged the partition in a coincidence of timing. Either way, your best hope for recovery lies on the macOS side. APFS is simply too new to have any native Linux recovery tools, at least as far as I know. Even if such tools were available in Linux, I'd be a little wary of them. I suggest you ask about recovery on a Mac forum. You might or might not get anything back, though; APFS is new enough that there's not yet much expertise available about recovering damaged filesystems, and it's conceivable that the Ubuntu installer (or whatever caused the damage) overwrote something truly critical. This is especially true if you used encryption on the macOS side -- although encryption has some big advantages, one big drawback is that minor filesystem damage can greatly complicate recovery, perhaps to the point of making it impossible. (I don't know how APFS fares in this respect.)

> Back on Ubuntu, `parted` complains about a corrupted GPT, but `gdisk` thinks it is fine. Here's the output of `parted -l`:

The `parted` output you quoted is pretty unclear about the nature of the alleged damage, and you've not provided any output from `gdisk`. In particular, the `v` option from `gdisk` (or `sgdisk -v`) might be helpful, as would be the complete output from when you launch `gdisk` and type `p` (or type `sudo gdisk -l`). You might have overlooked a `gdisk` warning; or it might have silently repaired some trivial problem that's provoking a complaint by `parted`; or `parted` might be complaining about something that's not really damage and that `gdisk` accepted; or `parted` might have noticed a problem that `gdisk` didn't. The distinctions between some of these things may be subjective -- although the GPT specification is much clearer than the non-existent MBR specification, it's got some ambiguities, so one program might interpret something unusual as damage whereas another might think it's OK. If the partition table *is* damaged, the [`gdisk` page on repairing GPT damage](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html) may be helpful. (Note: I'm the author of `gdisk`.) Without knowing precisely what `gdisk` thinks of the disk, though, I can't offer more specific advice on how to repair it, or even if it needs repair.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Rod. Yes, the installer wrote stuff on my drive. Later I mentioned (a bit buried in the comments) that “The problem is not the partition table, it is that Ubuntu overwrote a whopping 2MB of the APFS container without confirmations or warnings.”. I agree with you w.r.t. encryption and that it makes it hard or impossible. I've already formatted and reinstalled almost all my apps. It's a bit disappointing because I lost my videogames save files and other trivial stuff. Going on I will no longer backup just the "important data", but everything.